# Arabic text in R graphics

Tags: r, unicode, arabic, farsi

I'm having a problem with plotting Arabic text, it looks good on the console, but it doesn't show up quite right. (flipped & separate letters)

Code:

```
x<-"السلام عليكم"
> x
[1] "السلام عليكم"
> plot(1:10,main=x)
```

gives

[image]

Some relevant session info:

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
```

I've tried, so many suggested solutions but they all just don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently [you are not the first to encounter the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423760/right-to-left-languages-support-in-r-using-mac).
If you have access to  a linux system this issue won't happen.
It is probably an issue with right to left support in R and R Studio for Mac OS.